# What would a typical packet of a DDOS attack look like?

Tags: ddos, packet

In terms of header, size and payload?

We've been learning about DDOS attacks in class and they've been telling us all of the abstract ideas, but haven't told us what the actual makeup of the packets being sent would look like and I'm curious.

Comment: They can look like valid packets.

Comment: But then how they can spoof their source addresses etc.?

Comment: Who said spoofing was required

Comment: Isn't it a very common thing for addresses to be spoofed in a DDOS attack?

Comment: Spoofing can be used, in *some* cases. But even then, the packet is perfectly valid: an address is an address.

Comment: It all makes more sense now that I've read your answer :)

Comment: DoS can be achieved by a single, specially crafted packet that exploits a problem in the server/router. DDoS is *distributed*, meaning it's about *volume*: no special crafting required.

Answer (score 4):

DDoS is devastating because it **can** use perfectly valid traffic, thereby bypassing defences looking for anomalies. It does it's damage due to the volume alone.

There are DDoS attacks that can take advantage of vulnerabilities, and their packets do have unique characteristics to look for, but that will depend on the vulnerability being exploited, so we cannot tell you what that looks like without knowing which specific DoS exploit you are wondering about.